# Why do we use this.load in c#?

Tags: c#, function, multimedia

I'm working on a multimedia assignment and I found that the Dr is using `this.load` in the code so...

- I don't understand why do we need this event handler as I think we can work without it.
- I don't get why do I need such a ready made function and how it would be useful in multimedia programming or gaming programming.

This is my code :

```
namespace changecolors
{

    public class Actor
    {
        public int X, Y, W, H;
        public Color cl;
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Actor> L = new List<Actor>();
        int pos = -1;
        public Form1()
        {

            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
            this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseDown);
        }

        void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                pos = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < L.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (e.X >= L[i].X
                        && e.X <= L[i].X + L[i].W
                        && e.Y >=L[i].Y
                        && e.Y <= L[i].Y + L[i].H)
                    {
                        pos = i;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (pos > -1)
                {
                    L[pos].Y += 10;
                }

            }
            DrawScene();

        }

      void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Space:
                    DrawScene();
                    break;
            }


        }

        void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int V = 100;
            Color[] z = { Color.DarkGray, Color.Red, Color.Blue };
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Actor pnn = new Actor();
                pnn.X = V;
                pnn.Y = 200;
                pnn.W = 70;
                pnn.H = 170;
                pnn.cl = z[i];

                V += pnn.W;

                L.Add(pnn);
            }
        }

        void DrawScene()
        {
            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.Clear(Color.MistyRose);

            for (int i = 0; i < L.Count; i++)
            {
                SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(L[i].cl);
                g.FillRectangle(br,
                                  L[i].X, L[i].Y,
                                  L[i].W, L[i].H);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have code in `Load` event you can remove that. It is generated by double clicking the form in design view.

Comment: The Load event provides a way to execute code when the form is being loaded without the caller having to make a call to a public method. It is up to you whether you *want* to use it or not. In your case however, I would be far for more worried about the lack of proper naming and structure of the code than about whether or not to use the load event.

Comment: i'm a beginner so that's why i'm asking :D well thank you @PeterBons